# Angular define route params from root

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink, angular-router-params

I want to make a route path from base url:

**my-domain.com/3**

It was not working with path: ':id' and the page will be stuck:

```
  export const routes: Route[] = [


{
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [IsAuthenticated],
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dashboard' },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('../pages/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'companys',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../pages/company/feature/company-shell/company-shell.module').then(m => m.CompanyShellModule)
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'users',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../pages/users/feature/users-shell/users-shell.module').then(m => m.UsersShellModule)
          },
          {
            path: 'shift',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../pages/shift/feature/shift-shell/shift-shell.module').then(m => m.ShiftShellModule)
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    canActivate: [IsNotAuthenticated],
    loadChildren: () => import('../auth/feature/auth-shell/auth-shell.module').then(m => m.AuthShellModule)
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
]
```

It was working if I put a routing name before:id but I want to know if it is possible to define it just with ':id':

```
  {
        path: 'client/:id',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'users',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../pages/users/feature/users-shell/users-shell.module').then(m => m.UsersShellModule)
          },
...
}
```

Now working with **my-domain.com/client/3**
instead of **my-domain.com/3**

Comment: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58106556/running-angular8-under-virtual-directory-on-iis-not-able-to-access-inner-links/75047452#75047452)! hope to help you! موفق باشی

Comment: It also not working on localhost:4200 so I don't think it's up to virtual directory, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should to set '' path for dashboard component.
try this:

```
  { 
    path: '', 
    loadChildren: () => import('../pages/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule) 
  },
  { 
    path: ':id',
    loadChildren: () => import('../pages/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
  }
```

Comment: I just updated the full routing path, path '' is already exist